# Does python all() function iterate over all elements?

Tags: python, performance, built-in

I'm wondering if the all() Python function iterates over all elements of the iterable passed by param.

Answer (score 3):

Only if necessary.  If it finds one which returns `False`, it bails out and returns `False` itself without looking at the remaining elements.

The analog `any()` does it likewise for the first `True` element.  If it finds any, it aborts and returns `True` itself.  Only if none of the elements are `True`, it looks at each and returns `False`.

Comment: The source code for these functions can be found here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Doc/library/functions.rst 
They are both simple loops that return as they find a value that would determine the outcome, as you say.